# A given column is not a column of the dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following splitting function:

```
from typing import Tuple
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def split_dataframe(
    
    df: pd.DataFrame, 
    target_feature: str, 
    split_ratio: int = 0.2

) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
     
    df_ = df.copy()
    
    X = df_.drop(target_feature, axis=1)
    y = df_[target_feature]
    
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    y = encoder.fit_transform(y)
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = split_ratio)
    
    return  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

I split the dataframe by using the following:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = split_dataframe(df, 'Банк')
```

I use pipeline to transform X_train and y_train

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from mlxtend.feature_selection import ColumnSelector
import category_encoders as ce

cat_pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ('selector', ColumnSelector(categorical_features)),
        ('encoder', ce.one_hot.OneHotEncoder())
    ]
)

num_pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ('selector', ColumnSelector(numeric_features)),
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())
    ]
)

preprocessor = FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[
        
        ('cat', cat_pipe),
        ('num', num_pipe)
    ]
)

new_df = pipe.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

And after that I got **ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe** and specifically **KeyError: 'Банк'**. I checked if the columns exist before of pass the dataframe to split in train and test. If i remove `X = df_.drop(target_feature, axis=1)` to `X = df_` everything works correctly but target feature still in X.

Comment: Try with `handle_unknown='ignore'` in `onehotencode` constructor.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thank you for your answer. I tryied and still got an error

Comment: I made a sample dataframe with a column called "Банк" and it was able to split it with no error. Please edit to include a sample of your `df` dataframe that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

I mage a mistake in `pipe.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)`, i changed it to `preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)` and it worked